# IIS 7 FTP Publishing: Windows User Gets 530 18 Error

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, ftp, sftp, visual-studio

Here's the problem, from the log (*ip & dns names sanitized*):

### FTP Service Log

```
2013-03-26 01:25:07 ORIGIN.IP - DESTINATION.IP 21 ControlChannelOpened - - 0 0 4ba4c190-09ca-45e3-a2ae-b19117d33b80 -
2013-03-26 01:25:07 ORIGIN.IP - DESTINATION.IP 21 AUTH TLS 234 0 0 4ba4c190-09ca-45e3-a2ae-b19117d33b80 -
2013-03-26 01:25:10 ORIGIN.IP - DESTINATION.IP 21 ControlChannelOpened - - 0 0 e6d0e58c-f555-41aa-9164-a29c5ba8f9bb -
2013-03-26 01:25:10 ORIGIN.IP - DESTINATION.IP 21 AUTH TLS 234 0 0 e6d0e58c-f555-41aa-9164-a29c5ba8f9bb -
```

### FTP Service 1 Log

```
2013-03-26 01:25:08 ORIGIN.IP - DESTINATION.IP 21 USER ftp.foo.bar.com|WDeployAdmin 331 0 0 4ba4c190-09ca-45e3-a2ae-b19117d33b80 - 
2013-03-26 01:25:08 ORIGIN.IP MACHINE-NAME\WDeployAdmin DESTINATION.IP 21 PASS *** 530 183 18 4ba4c190-09ca-45e3-a2ae-b19117d33b80 / 
2013-03-26 01:25:10 ORIGIN.IP - DESTINATION.IP 21 ControlChannelClosed - - 0 0 4ba4c190-09ca-45e3-a2ae-b19117d33b80 -
```

*(developer moonlighting as sysadmin here; I have no idea why there are two different services that are doing the logs.)*

According to [MS doc](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969061), FTP log codes:

> 183   *??? (not in doc, can't find win32-substatus code table)*
>
> 234   Security data exchange complete.
>
> 331   User name okay, need password.
>
> 530   Not logged in.
>
> 18    Invalid configuration.

### IIS Config

Default Web Site, FTP Publishing enabled.

Bindings:
`*:21:ftp.foo.bar.com`

Physical path: `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot`

Specified Users:
`Allow WDeployAdmin read write`

FTP Authentication: `Basic enabled, no Default domain`

### Windows User

`WDeployAdmin` has `full control` over `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot`

### FTP Client

Visual Studio 2012, Copy Web Site

Server: `ftps://foo.bar.com` Port: `21` `Passive Mode`

Username: ftp.foo.bar.com|WDeployAdmin

Error message:

> The username or password you have entered is incorrect, or you do not
>   have authorization to perform this action.

Error message 2 (after declining to attempt connection again):

> Unable to open the Web site 'ftps://foo.bar.com'. You are not
>   authorized to perform the current operation.

### Diagnostic Steps Taken

I tried appending a sub-folder of wwwroot to the connection, eg `ftps://foo.bar.com/baz`, same error.

I've reset the password of `WDeployAdmin` to verify that it is correct.

I've restarted IIS, and refreshed the Default Web Site http and ftp services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These changes resolved the problem. My retroactive hypothesis is that the extra hostheader binding was messing up user authentication somehow.

1. Removed extraneous IIS FTP Site (that had been stopped, but still).
2. Removed FTP Publishing from Default Web Site.
3. Started FTP Publishing from Default Web Site. No bindings other than to IP. MACHINE-NAME in  Default domain.
4. Restart Microsoft FTP Service from Services control panel ([nice tip](http://tangercp.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/setting-up-iis-7-ftp-ssl-all-details-and-steps-required/))
5. Client: same setup, except no hostheader in username, just the username.